# Inserting citation with reftex-citation breaks Emacs buffer

Tags: emacs

I am trying to get started with RefTeX in Emacs 24.1.50.3, built `--without-x`. Running

```
(reftex-citation)
```

seems to work at first. I can enter a regex and get a list of matching citations in my bibliography. However, selecting an entry makes the buffer stops working. Attempting to navigate gives the following error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Marker does not point anywhere")
  posn-at-point()
  line-move-visual(1 nil)
  line-move(1 nil nil 1)
  byte-code("\302\303\211   $\207" [arg try-vscroll line-move nil] 5)
  next-line(1 1)
  call-interactively(next-line nil nil)
```

This should not be caused by my init.el, because it occurs even when I launch emacs with `--no-site-files` and enter `(reftex-mode)` manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `--no-site-file` does not inhibit your init.el file.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Initial Options` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Start `emacs -Q` to be sure this is not being caused by non-standard libraries.

If so, then it sounds like a bug, in which case:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Oh, thanks for correcting me. The problem persists even after `emacs -Q`. However, before submitting a bug report, I built the latest version of Emacs. RefTeX works now, so it must already have been fixed. I should have checked that first.